# what is the purpose use for sagemaker config.yaml?

Tags: config, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

On sagemaker studio, I often get this on the console:

`sagemaker.config INFO - Not applying SDK defaults from location: /etc/xdg/sagemaker/config.yaml sagemaker.config INFO - Not applying SDK defaults from location: /home/sagemaker-user/.config/sagemaker/config.yaml sagemaker.config INFO - Not applying SDK defaults from location: /etc/xdg/sagemaker/config.yaml sagemaker.config INFO - Not applying SDK defaults from location: /home/sagemaker-user/.config/sagemaker/config.yaml sagemaker.config INFO - Not applying SDK defaults from location: /etc/xdg/sagemaker/config.yaml sagemaker.config INFO - Not applying SDK defaults from location: /home/sagemaker-user/.config/sagemaker/config.yaml`

I haven't seen any documentation anywhere about this config file. Why should I use it? Is it a way to store environmental variables? Is it a way to customizer SDK functionality? Is it to be used along the lines of dotenv?

I googled around and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same warning and this was the first search result.  A few minutes of searching around unearthed the links below.  The tl;dr seems to be that config.yaml files are a way to ensure that appropriate security-related settings are applied for sensitive applications (e.g., machine learning on healthcare information).  There's probably a LOT more to it than that, but I'm an AWS beginner myself, so I can't provide much more information than that. Good luck!

[Configure & use SageMaker defaults](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/configure-and-use-defaults-for-amazon-sagemaker-resources-with-the-sagemaker-python-sdk/)

The doc page is here:
[SageMaker config.yaml file documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/train-remote-decorator-config.html)

Comment: i hate sagemaker's lack of quality documentation :(